# Item in array deleted but UI not update in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-elements

This app developed by react-native. I know that this question can be duplicated but I tried all solution, and they did not work.

I'm very confused. When some item **adding/pushing** array in object, UI element is updated. But When I **delete/splice** in same array, this mechanism not working and UI element is not updated. Why?

```
function createWordsetObject() {
  const object = {
    name: '',
    words: [],
  }

  return object
}

export default function AddWordScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const [wordsetObject, setWordsetObj] = useState(
    route.params == null ? createWordsetObject() : route.params.wordSetObject
  )
  const [wordsetName, setWordsetName] = useState(
    route.params == null ? '' : route.params.wordSetObject.name
  )
  const [word, setWord] = useState('')
  const [meaning, setMeaning] = useState('')

  const onPressAddButtonHandler = () => {
    if (word != null && meaning != null) {
      var addRecord = { word: word, meaning: meaning }
      wordsetObject.words.push(addRecord)
      setWord('')
      setMeaning('')
      printLog()
    }
  }
  const onPressDeleteWordButton = index => {
    var modifiedObj = wordsetObject
    if (modifiedObj.words.length > 0) {
      console.log(modifiedObj.words.length)
      modifiedObj.words.splice(index, 1)
    }
    setWordsetObj(modifiedObj)
    console.log(wordsetObject.words.length)
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {wordsetObject.words.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <ListItem
            key={index}
            title={item.word}
            subtitle={item.meaning}
            bottomDivider
            rightIcon={
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <MCIcon name="pencil" size={22} />
                <MCIcon
                  name="delete"
                  size={22}
                  color="red"
                  onPress={() => onPressDeleteWordButton(index)}
                />
              </View>
            }
          />
        )
      })}
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create new object instead of manipulating existing one.

```js
const onPressDeleteWordButton = (index) => {

        if(wordsetObject.words.length) {
          setWordsetObj(modifiedObj => {
            return {
              ...modifiedObj,
              words: modifiedObj.words.filter((pr, ind) => ind !== index)
            }
          });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its working. Thanks quick response but why did not work manipulation way?

Comment: [Don't know, theres only a guide in docs not to do that](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5/#:~:text=React%20state%20should%20be%20treated,replace%20the%20mutation%20you%20made.)

Comment: @forever_software When you use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method, it **changes** the Array but when you [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) / `spread operator`/ `Object.assign`, these create **new** Array / Object. **New** is the key point here. Because React does **shallow compare** to detect changes to re-render the UI. When you modify the existing JS Object/Array, React sees that object still has the same old reference, so it doesn't re-render.